# Where to put Interactivity Triggers In ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I have the following XAML for a CustomControl:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--triggers-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to use Interactivity / EventToCommand to capture a KeyDown event for the entire CustomControl.

Something like:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArs="True"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My question is- where do I put the triggers in the ControlTemplate markup? I want to do the equivalent of this in the code behind:

```
this.KeyDown += ItemView_KeyDown;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put they inside ControlTemplate or inside Border element:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArs="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Border>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--triggers-->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type itvw:ItemView}">
            <Border>                
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArs="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--triggers-->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference? If I put mouse click events in the border the textbox always seems to take focus and the event doesn't fire (I was trying to do a single click to select the ItemView and a second click to start editing the textbox).

Comment: Also the first option complains about ControlTemplate not deriving from DependencyObject. Any ideas?

Comment: @jidl did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No I didn't. Sorry.